# How many associative binary operations are there on a 2 element set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, associativity

We can easily find commutative binary operations on a 2 element set from the truth table (if ab=ba then the operation is commutative, thus there are 8 commutative binary operations in a 2 element set).

Is there a similar method or algorithm to find how many and what are the associative binary operations in a 2 element set?

If there isn't a way to quickly check, we would need to test all 8 possible inputs independently (if not commutative) and only 4 (if commutative) - which is still a lot for a 2 element set - 96 total (16 operations, 8 are commutative, so 8*4+8*8=96).

A generalization to an n-element set be very helpful.

Comment: Considering that [this 7-page paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.403.2871&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (the first google result I got) is needed for the number of associative binary operators on a $5$-element set, I don't think there is a nice and simple general way (at least not a known one). Although since they clearly haven't checked all possible 3-element multiplications for all the 298,023,223,876,953,125 possible operations (at least I don't _think_ they have, I haven't actually read the thing) you might be able to find some nice shortcuts.

Comment: The result in that paper leads to [OEIS sequence A023814](https://oeis.org/A023814), which contains the counts up to $9$-element set and a few links but no results. (Note that the counts up to $9$-element sets where shortly before that paper was published, so apparently that wasn't state of the art.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check every single possibility. For your set use $\{+1, -1\}$.

- Suppose $B$ is commutative, i.e. $B(a,b)=B(b,a)$ for all $a,b\in \{\pm1\}$, and associative . Then if we put $B(a,a)=x_a$ and $B(a,-a)=B(-a,a)=y$ (note the latter is independent of $a$). The triple $x_{\pm1},y$ is enough to completely determine $B$. The only non-trivial associativity equation in this case yields
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  B(x_y,-y)&=B(B(y,y), -y)=B(y,B(y,-y))=B(y,y)=x_y\\
  B(x_{-y},y)&=B(B(-y,-y), y)=B(-y,B(-y,y))=B(-y,y)=y
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  The possible solutions are **(1)** $x_y=-x_{-y}=y$, **(2)** $x_y=x_{-y}=y$, **(3)** $x_y=x_{-y}=-y$. And these are the only possibilities. 
  So programatically, if $B(1,-1)=B(-1,1)$, simply calculate $x_{+1}, x_{-1}, y$ and check if $x_y=y$ (case 1 and 2 together), or else if $x_y=x_{-y}$.
- Suppose $B$ is NOT commutative but associative. Then $B(a,-a)=-B(-a,a)$. Define $x_a=B(a,a)$ and $y=B(1,-1)$. Now associativity gives
  $$
  B(x_a,a)=B(B(a,a),a)=B(a,B(a,a))=B(a,x_a)
  $$
  meaning $a,x_a$ commute. This in turn means, $x_a=a$ necessarily.

Before we continue, note that the equalities
$$
\begin{aligned}
y&=B(1,y)=-B(-1,-y)=B(y,-1)=-B(-y,1)\\
1&=B(y,1)=B(1,-y)=-B(-y,-1)=-B(-1,y)
\end{aligned}
$$
are tautologically true no matter what $y$ is. Writting the most general associativity equality
$$
B(B(a,b),c)=B(a, B(b,c))
$$
assuming not all $a,b,c$ are the same, we have the following possibilities, $a=b=-c$, $a=-b=c$ and $-a=b=c$. This leads to three associativity relation
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(\mathrm{sgn}\: a)y=B(a,-a)=B(B(a,a),-a)=B(a, B(a,-a))=B(a,(\mathrm{sgn}\: a)y)\\
&B((\mathrm{sgn}\: a)y,a)=B(B(a,-a),a)=B(a, B(-a,a))=B(a, -(\mathrm{sgn}\: a)y)\\
&B(-(\mathrm{sgn}\: a)y,a)=B(B(-a,a),a)=B(-a,B(a,a))=B(-a,a)=-(\mathrm{sgn}\: a)y
\end{aligned}
$$
all of which are tautologically true. This means we are completely free to choose $y$ as we please. So programatically, if $y=B(1,-1)\neq B(-1,1)$, then simply check if $B(1,1)=1$ and $B(-1,-1)$, because that's the only possibility.

Assuming I have not done any stupid mistakes (which I'm quite afraid might have happened), you should be able to rule whether a binary relation $B$ is associative or not with like four if-clauses. I'm too lazy to actually count how many binary relations I just created, but it's quite straightforward to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

The comments show what there might be for the $n$-element set. As for the $2$-element set, we can enumerate all possible binary operations (realizing that Hamed's answer shows we don't necessarily *have* to do this), and then check which ones are associative. Assume we are writing $a\star b = f(a,b),$ where $\star$ is the binary operation and $f$ we will designate as a number from $1$ to $16,$ and we're going to use the $2$-element set $\{T, F\},$ so that we can pull in expressions from boolean logic. So we create the following tables:
$$
\begin{array}{|cc|cccccccc|}\hline
a &b &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8  \\ \hline
T &T &F &F &F &F &F &F &F &F\\ \hline
T &F &F &F &F &F &T &T &T &T \\ \hline
F &T &F &F &T &T &F &F &T &T \\ \hline
F &F &F &T &F &T &F &T &F &T  \\ \hline
\text{Expr:} & &F &\lnot(a\lor b) & &\lnot\,a & &\lnot\,b &a\otimes b &\lnot (a\land b) \\ \hline
\text{Assoc.?} & &T &F &F &F &F &F &T &F\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{|cc|cccccccc|}\hline
a &b &9 &10 &11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 \\ \hline
T &T &T &T &T &T &T &T &T &T \\ \hline
T &F &F &F &F &F &T &T &T &T \\ \hline
F &T &F &F &T &T &F &F &T &T \\ \hline
F &F &F &T &F &T &F &T &F &T \\ \hline
\text{Expr:} & &a\land b &a \iff b &b &a\implies b &a &b\implies a &a\lor b &T \\ \hline
\text{Assoc.?} & &T &T &T &F &T &F &T &T \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Here is some Python code used to test each option:

```
def f(a: bool, b: bool) -> bool:
    return a or b 

def test_assoc() -> bool:
    values = [True, False]
    associative = True
    for a in values:
        for b in values:
            for c in values:
                test = (f(f(a, b), c) == f(a, f(b, c)))
                associative = associative and test
    return associative
```

You just change the definition of `f` to match which function you're testing, and run the `test_assoc` function again.

There are definitely some surprises in these results.